# Delay restart of processes in monit

Tags: monit

Can I modify montrc so that it will not restart process immediately.  The process has to be down for a full cycle before a restart is triggered.  This is so I can keep my existing capistrano deploys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like :

```
check process x with pidfile /var/run/x.pid
   every y cycles
```

or

```
start program = "/etc/init.d/x start" with timeout 90 seconds
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your 2nd option: here's the Monit doc about `with timeout`: _In the case of a process check, Monit will wait up to 30 seconds for the start/stop action to finish before giving up and report an error. You can override this timeout using the TIMEOUT option or globally using the set limits._ I think this is the allowed time to start, not the interval between stop and the next start.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is currently possible to do that if you're monitoring only the PID file. If however, you are also monitoring the service by listening in on a port, you can add a `if failed port 8080 X times within Y cycles then restart` clause. Monit will then curl that port every cycle, and when the count of failures reaches X across Y cycles, it will attempt to restart the service.

Keep in mind that this only affects the port monitor. If monit notices the PID file is gone, it will immediately try to restart it.

Comment: You could 'monitor' a fake PID file though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
check process x with pidfile /var/run/x.pid
  if does not exist for 2 cycles then start
```

This will wait a minimum of 1 full cycle before restarting the dead process.